# 'Member of' in Oracle

Tags: oracle, plsql

I am trying to use `member of` in Oracle.
I am able to use this when table type is of number or any other data type. Below is the code for this:

```
declare
    type t is table of number;
    lt t;
begin
    select channel_key
    bulk collect into lt
    from dim_channels;

    if 22 member of lt then
        dbms_output.put_line('ss');
    end if;
end;
```

How do I use `member of` when the table is based on a record as in the code below.

```
declare
    type rt is record 
    (
      channel_key number(10),
      channel_code varchar2(100)
    );

    type t is table of rt;
    lt t;
    lrt rt;
begin
    select channel_key, channel_code
    bulk collect into lt
    from dim_channels;
end;
```

Answer (score 4):

This won't work with plain local PL/SQL record types. To include more attributes you will need an object type with a `MAP` or `ORDER` function:

```
create or replace type demo_ot as object
( channel_key integer
, channel_code varchar2(30)
, map member function demo_map return varchar2 )
/

create or replace type body demo_ot as
    map member function demo_map return varchar2
    is
    begin
        return self.channel_key || '<#>' || self.channel_code;
    end demo_map;
end;
/

declare
    type demo_t is table of demo_ot;  -- You would normally create this globally in SQL
    my_set     demo_t;
    my_object  demo_ot;
begin
    select demo_ot(ckey, ccode)
    bulk collect into my_set
    from   ( select 1 as ckey, 'One' as ccode from dual
             union all
             select 2 as ckey, 'Two' as ccode from dual );

    my_object := demo_ot(2, 'Two');

    if my_object member of my_set then
        dbms_output.put_line('Member found');
    else
        dbms_output.put_line('Member not found');
    end if;
end;
/
```

Answer (score 0):

I created below code to test it

```
create or replace PROCEDURE P_MEMBER_OF_TEST(p_fname IN VARCHAR2, 
        p_lname in varchar2)
              AS
          type type_rec is record 
              (
             first_name employees.first_name%type,
               last_name employees.last_name%type
             );
          TYPE T_TAB_TYPE IS TABLE OF type_rec;
           T_TAB T_TAB_TYPE;
           t_rec type_rec;
           i int;
         BEGIN
            t_rec.first_name := p_fname;
            t_rec.last_name := p_lname;
            SELECT FIRST_NAME,last_name bulk collect INTO T_TAB FROM 
           EMPLOYEES;

           dbms_output.put_line(t_rec.first_name || ',' || t_rec.last_name);

          IF t_rec MEMBER OF T_TAB THEN
             DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE ('YES');
          ELSE
             DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('NO');
          END IF;

        END;
```

It compiled with no issues however when i execute it i get error that my connection has been reset , when i comment the if-else-end if block . it gets executed. Can you also suggest what is the problem in code @William Robertson

Comment: `type type_rec is record` - it's the wrong type for this operation, yet somehow the compiler misses this or chooses not to fail compilation, and instead it crashes at runtime. If you `alter session set plsql_warnings='enable:all'` you'll get a compiler warning `PLW-05022: argument 'T_REC' is not comparable` (in 12.1.0.2.0 at least).